# Integral closure under completion

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a commutative local ring with identity and $I$ an ideal in $R$. If $I$ is integrally closed, does it follow that $I\hat{R}$ is integrally closed? If not, is this true with certain assumptions on $R$?

EDIT: OK, I read that a necessary condition for integral closure to commute with localization is that $R$ be analytically unramified. I could not find a sufficient condition though.